# What is Suitable pageUp Key in Ubuntu 16.04 of Macbook Air?

Tags: keyboard, 16.04, macbook, usability

There are some configs which use the button. I have replaced them now but I think pageUp can be necessary key in some applications. System: Macbook Air 2013-mid.

---

What is suitable pageUp key in Ubuntu 16.04 of Macbook Air?

Comment: @wutangforever Please, make it an answer. I will review it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MacBook Pro (8.1) with Ubuntu 16.04, fn + control + up arrow is the equivalent of pageUp. Perhaps it is the same for Macbook Air?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works also in Macbook Air 2013-mid.